# TemporalType.TIMESTAMP whit java.util.Date don't function (hibernate version 3.2.7.ga)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, date

I have this in a class

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "data_creazione")
private Date dataCreazione;
```

the object is saved if i put null on db on data_creazione
 I do:

```
Date data=new Date();
newAccordo.setDataCreazione(data);
```

and also instead:

```
newAccordo.setDataCreazione(new Timestamp(data.getTime()));
```

but the object don't be saved. I look for what put in query and is '2014-07-11 16:40:04' that is a normal date time. if i put it manualy it work.
in the db I try to put datetime and timestamp but don't write inside db anyway.

if i put:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
```

he write in db the date and the time, but after when I stamp it in jsp I see only right time and the date from util.date start. so i can't use this escamotage.
I think the problem can be in hibernate version.

what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
Date data=new Date();
newAccordo.setDataCreazione(new Timestamp(data.getTime());  // data --> date ??
```

Because the column type is Timestamp (yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.), not Date(yyyy-mm-dd) type. Make sure you import

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
```

Also set your hibernate to `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`, which will automatically update the column data type.

Comment: Yes, `data` is italian for date.

Comment: i put the <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> and use newAccordo.setDataCreazione(new Timestamp(data.getTime()); but nothing change.

Comment: then we need to see your save() method

Comment: `code      public void save(Accordi accordo){
  Session sess = getSessionFactory().openSession();
  Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
  try{
  sess.save(accordo);
  tx.commit();
  }catch(Exception e){
  tx.rollback();
 }
 sess.close();
 }`

Comment: my save function work if i don't pass the data or if i put @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) instead of @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)

Comment: then the next question is how you created the accordo object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by generating the timestamp from mysql. anyway i think is a bug of the old hibernate version (3.2.7.ga) that I'm using or of the Annotation version (3.3.0.ga)

anyway the model is

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "data_creazione")
private Date dataCreazione;

public Date getDataCreazione() {
    return dataCreazione;
}

public void setDataCreazione(Date dataCreazione) {
    this.dataCreazione = dataCreazione;
}
```